# Scraping a specific table from a URL when read_html is pulling the first table by default

Tags: r

Trying to pull the leaderboard from [this URL](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=1&type=c,7,5,14,11,21,22,54,58&season=2024&month=1000&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2024-03-18&enddate=2024-03-24&v_cr=legacy), but it's catching the hidden Standings table instead.

```
url <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=1&type=c,7,5,14,11,21,22,54,58&season=2024&month=1000&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2024-03-18&enddate=2024-03-24&v_cr=legacy"

l1 <- html_nodes(l1, 'table')

daily <- html_table(l1, fill = TRUE)\[\[7\]\]


tibble: 5 × 3X1    X2    X3l1 <- read_html(url)
```

Which produces:

> <chr> <chr> <chr>

> 1 BAL   CHW   LAA
> 2 BOS   CLE   OAK
> 3 NYY   DET   SEA
> 4 TBR   KCR   TEX
> 5 TOR   MIN   HOU

What I'm trying to pull is the player stats:

1   Mookie Betts    LAD 6   9   2   1   0   0       0.3

2   Tyler Wade  SDP 3   5   1   0   0   0       0.1

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspecting the web page, I see that the table you want has id='LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00'. I used `xpath =` with `html_element()` to locate this element, then `html_table()` to read it.

The formatting is not great due to the controls at the top so I read it into `rough_table` then extracted the data and the names into `table`.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=1&type=c,7,5,14,11,21,22,54,58&season=2024&month=1000&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2024-03-18&enddate=2024-03-24&v_cr=legacy"

# read the page
l1 <- read_html(url)

# find the element containing the required table
leaderboard_element <- html_element(l1, xpath = "//table[@id = 'LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00']")

# read this into a data.frame
rough_leaderboard  <- html_table(leaderboard_element)

# the actual data starts in row 4 ...
leaderboard <- rough_leaderboard[4:nrow(rough_leaderboard),]

# ... and the column names are in row 2
names(leaderboard) <- unlist(rough_leaderboard[2,])


leaderboard
# # a tibble: 22 × 11
#    `#`   name        team  h     ab    bb    hr    sb    cs    fld   war  
#    <chr> <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#  1 1     mookie bet… lad   6     9     2     1     0     0     ""    0.3  
#  2 2     tyler wade  sdp   3     5     1     0     0     0     ""    0.1  
#  3 3     will smith  lad   5     10    1     0     0     0     "0.0" 0.2  
#  4 4     jake crone… sdp   4     8     0     0     0     0     ""    0.1  
#  5 5     jose azocar sdp   1     2     0     0     0     0     ""    0.0  
#  6 6     xander bog… sdp   4     9     1     0     0     0     ""    0.1  
#  7 7     freddie fr… lad   1     6     4     0     0     0     ""    0.1  
#  8 8     max muncy   lad   3     9     2     0     0     0     ""    0.1  
#  9 9     manny mach… sdp   1     7     3     1     0     0     ""    0.0  
# 10 10    jurickson … sdp   1     5     2     0     0     0     ""    0.0  
# # ℹ 12 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to read the header and the body of the table, but this seems to work for me.

Comment: I ran this, but it's giving me the following: Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"